# Extract text from inner exception messages

Tags: c#, regex, exception

I have this database exception message

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_dbo.MyApprovals_dbo.My_ApproverMyId". The conflict occurred in database "DatabaseDev", table "dbo.DatabaseTable", column 'ApproverPositionId'.
>   The statement has been terminated.

I need to extract two components

```
DELETE 
DatabaseTable
```

I am trying using the below regular expression

```
var result = Regex.Match("The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint \"FK_dbo.MyApprovals_dbo.My_ApproverMyId\". The conflict occurred in database \"DatabaseDev\", table \"dbo.DatabaseTable\", column 'ApproverPositionId'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated.").Groups[1].Value;
```

Comment: Are you looking for a more general version? Or do you only want to extract `DELETE` and `DatabaseTable`?

Comment: @SebastianLenartowicz I just need to extract DELETE and DatabaseTable. Of course, if there is a more general way the better

Comment: Try `var results  = Regex.Matches(str, @"[A-Z]+(?=\s+statement)|(?<=,\s+table\s+""\w+\.)[^""]+").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToList();`. See [this demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5bA-Z%5d%2b(%3f%3d%5cs%2bstatement)%7c(%3f%3c%3d%2c%5cs%2btable%5cs%2b%22%5cw%2b%5c.)%5b%5e%22%5d%2b&i=The+DELETE+statement+conflicted+with+the+REFERENCE+constraint+%22FK_dbo.MyApprovals_dbo.My_ApproverMyId%22.+The+conflict+occurred+in+database+%22DatabaseDev%22%2c+table+%22dbo.DatabaseTable%22%2c+column+%27ApproverPositionId%27.%0d%0aThe+statement+has+been+terminated.).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It is not getting the DatabaseTable

Comment: @ove - It does, see *Table* section on the regex tester page. **See http://ideone.com/o78X82**

Comment: @ove: Do you find any of the solutions OK? Or do you really want to get 1 match with 2 capture groups? Like in http://ideone.com/seaz72?

Comment: Ok, I posted my latest attempt, hope that is helpful enough.

Answer (score 0):

For your specific question, the regex you want is `(DELETE).+database "(.+?)"`, and the two capture groups will contain what you want.

A more general version (better for logging errors) is as follows:

`The (.+?) statement.+the(.+?)\". The conflict.+(database ".+?", table ".+?", column '.+?')`

The capture groups will spit out (in order) the statement (DELETE, SELECT, etc.), the constraint that was hit, and the DB, table, and column. Naturally, this will only work for error messages with this specific structure.

Overall code looks something like this:

```
Match m = Regex.match(errorString, @"The (.+?) statement.+the(.+?)""\. The conflict.+(database "".+?"", table "".+?"", column '.+?')");
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].value);
```

It should be noted that I'm not a C# guy (I was answering the regex question), so this may have issues.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `Regex.Match()` requires at least 2 arguments, a string and a regex pattern (you missed the regex pattern part).

Also, when you run a regex match, you should check if there is a match first with `Match.Success`. Else, you might get an exception.

You can use a simple regex that will capture both values you need into groups:

```
var str = "The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint \"FK_dbo.MyApprovals_dbo.My_ApproverMyId\". The conflict occurred in database \"DatabaseDev\", table \"dbo.DatabaseTable\", column 'ApproverPositionId'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated.";
var m = Regex.Match(str, @"(?s)(?<delete>[A-Z]+)\s+statement.*?,\s+table\s+""\w+\.(?<table>[^""]+)");
if (m.Success) {
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["delete"].Value); // => DELETE
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["table"].Value);  // => DatabaseTable
}
```

See [this IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/seaz72)

The regex matches:

- `(?s)` - a singleline modifier to make `.` match any character including a newline (just in case you might have a newline in the string in between the two groups)
- `(?<delete>[A-Z]+)\s+statement` - 1+ ASCII uppercase letters (`[A-Z]+`) captured into Group "delete", 1+ whitespaces (`\s+`) followed with a `statement` substring
- `.*?,` - any 0+ characters up to the first `,`
- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces
- `table\s+` - `table` substring followed with 1+ whitespaces
- `""\w+\.` - a `"`, 1+ word characters, and a literal `.`
- `(?<table>[^""]+)`  - Group "table" matching 1+ characters other than `"`.